# Extracting char* from a str PyObject in Python 3

Tags: python, c, string, d, pyobject

Have anybody tried extracting a `char*` from a Python 3 `PyObject*` having type name `str`? Normal strings in Python 3 have type name `str` in the C API.

For Python 2 one can use `PyString_Check()` and `PyString_AsStringAndSize` present in the header `stringobject.h`.

For Python 3 this header is not present, instead there is `bytesobject` and `unicodeobject.h`. For the latter, using D, I put together

```
private const(char)[] toChars(PyObject* value) {
    import deimos.python.unicodeobject : PyUnicode_Check;
    if (PyUnicode_Check!()(value)) {
        Py_ssize_t size;
        const char* s = PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(value, &size);
        return s[0 .. size];
    }
    ...
}
// https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize
const(char)* PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize(PyObject* unicode, Py_ssize_t* size);
```

but that doesn't match a `value` being passed a standard Python 3 string (literal) of type `str` created via `str(...)`. Moreover, I couldn't come up with a way to construct a "unicode string" in Python 3 that matches `PyUnicode_Check` in the C API. I'm utterly confused. I could try converting it to a bytes object and use the functions in `bytesobject.h` but that doesn't seem right either?

I've also tried

```
PyBytes_AsStringAndSize(PyObject* obj, char** s, Py_ssize_t* len);
```

but that fails complaining about obj not being of type `bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PyArg_ParseTuple()` with the "s" format.

For example in 'C',

```
const char * toChars(PyObject * _value)
{
  const char *value;
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(_value, "s", &value))
      return NULL; /* fails! */
  return value;
}
```

Assuming you know the object will live for the lifetime of the use of string, or you may need to bump reference counts.

I think this works with all versions of Python and I have used it with 3.8.10.

`PyUnicode_FromString()` will work if you need to supply a new string to Python.

Comment: I believe there is all sort of locale and other compositional issues (a PyObject is multiple objects, etc).  I tried `PyUnicode_AsUTF8AndSize()` and gave up.